# Need Help to convert Encryption Blowfish php to Nodejs using crypto

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

Hello I need help to convert My PHP encryption function to Nodejs using crypto module:

This code is already working

```
// Constructor params
$this->algorithm = "blowfish";
$this->token = "3SzzaErRzj0#RuGr@JTkh[MO0AMIW*d!Sul/CEL!*rPnq$oOEgYaH}fNw{jw1b/DyLUdL])+JOMES@Z7MIRI>(p*nY{yl%h]4ylx";

    public function decrypt($string)
    {

        $key = hash('sha256', $this->token);
        list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($string), 2);
        return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, $this->algorithm, $key, 0, $iv);
    }

    public function encrypt($string)
    {

        $output = false;
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->algorithm));
        // hash
        $key = hash('sha256', $this->token);
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $this->algorithm, $key, 0, $iv);
        return base64_encode($output . '::' . $iv);
    }
```

And the code in nodejs, i made decipher worked properly, but cipher is not working

```
    const crypto = require('crypto');

    const decipher = async (alg, key, value) => {
            const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
            hash.update(key);
            let token = hash.digest('hex');

            let buff = new Buffer.from(value, 'base64');
            let [encrypted, iv] = buff.toString('ascii').split('::', 2);
            iv = new Buffer.from(iv);

            const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(alg, token, iv);
            let decrypted = await decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'ascii');
            decrypted += decipher.final('ascii');
            return decrypted;
    }

   /* this one is not working */
   const cipher = async (alg, key, value) => {


        let iv = crypto.randomBytes(8);

        var sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256');
        sha256.update(key);
        var newkey = sha256.digest('base64');

        var encryptor = await crypto.createCipheriv(alg, newkey, iv);

        encrypted = encryptor.update(value, 'utf8', 'base64') + encryptor.final('base64');

        var final = encrypted + "::" +iv;

        let buf = Buffer.from(final);
        let encodedData = buf.toString('base64');

        return encodedData;

}
```

any help to help me get my job done I appreciate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following changes must be done in the `cipher` method of the NodeJS code:

- The key must be encoded hexadecimal:

  ```
  var newkey = sha256.digest('hex');
  ```
- The IV must be appended as binary string:

  ```
  var final = encrypted + "::" + iv.toString('binary');
  ```
- And the data must be parsed as binary string:

  ```
  let buf = Buffer.from(final, 'binary');
  ```

With these changes the `cipher` method in the NodeJS code is compatible with the `encrypt` method in the PHP code.

The `cipher` method uses UTF8 encoding, the `decipher` method uses ASCII encoding, so that only ASCII encodabled texts can be decrypted correctly. To remove the restriction to ASCII encoding, the following changes are necessary in the `decipher` method:

- The encoding into a binary string has to be done with `binary` and not with `ascii`:

  ```
  let [encrypted, iv] = buff.toString('binary').split('::', 2);
  iv = new Buffer.from(iv, 'binary');
  ```
- And the output encoding must be `utf8` instead of `ascii`:

  ```
  let decrypted =  decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
  decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
  ```

With these changes the NodeJS and the PHP code are compatible. Note also:

- Actually none of the NodeJS-functions applied is asynchronous, so the use of `async`/`await` is not really necessary.
- The `new` before `Buffer.from` can be omitted.
- The algorithm is specified with `blowfish`, which corresponds to `bf-cbc` and means Blowfish in CBC mode.
- A 32 bytes key is generated with SHA256 and returned as hexadecimal string (with 64 bytes/chars), therefore a 64 byte key is used. For Blowfish a maximum key length of 56 bytes is defined, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25789).
- SHA256 is used as key derivation function, more secure is e.g. PBKDF2 (at least for weak passwords), [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70265).
- The IV, separated by a delimiter, is appended to the Base64 encoded ciphertext, and the resulting data are Base64 encoded (i.e. the ciphertext is therefore Base64 encoded twice). Usually IV and ciphertext (in this order) are concatenated on a binary level and the resulting data are Base64 encoded. A separator is not necessary, since the length of the IV corresponds to the block size and is therefore known.

Comment: what a complete answer, thanks a alot for the help, in a few hours i will make the changes. =D